# Capture big movement with Android Smartphone

Tags: java, android, smartphone

I would like to be able to capture big movement on my Android phone for a game. For example a stroke with the arm to the right, left or other direction and to be able to differentiate them.

Is there something that already exist for this ?

What sensor should i use for that purpose and why ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use accelerometer. The direction in which you get a difference in acceleration helps you detect the movement of the arm. Don't pay attention to values of the accelerometer, rather to the differences: you can't detect where the arm is, neither if it moved, but you can detect if it accelerated and decelerated to move.

Comment: So accelerometer is best than giroscope for this ? I've seen accelerometer and linear acceleration sensor, which one is the best ?

Comment: I never used a gyroscope, but I think it wouldn't help you much, and I believe that is also not very common on devices (but i may be wrong). As far as I know (but i might be wrong here too) also "accelerometer" and "linear accelerometer" are actually synonymous. It gives you acceleration in 3 axis, so gravity included. You can detect when a movement starts and ends, and the direction. You might try to integrate that information with the gyroscope (if it is installed) to detect movement + rotation.